# Set value to nicedit - which uses textarea as an instance

Tags: jquery, nicedit

Here is the link, your webbrowser will navigate to: http://thocong.net/dang-tin.html

I'm developing an app, which will auto post news. 
When setting value to controls on webpage, all controls are ok, but i cannot to set value to editor (NicEdit). This editor used TextArea tags as instance. I had set value to textarea, but when the news is posted I cannot find contents that set to this textarea.
So, pls help me to solve this issue.

Below are codes i'm using to set value to controls on webpages (above link)

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser.Document;
HtmlElement description = document.GetElementById("content");//id of textarea
description .SetAttribute("value", info.Content);
```

->> Summary: Pls tell me How to set values to nice editor?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a very old question but in case you haven't yet found the answer here it is:

```
nicEditors.findEditor( "your-textarea-id" ).setContent( 'some value' );
```

Comment: @anubhava it says *setContent* undefined when I call in jquery.ready()

Comment: Make sure nicEdit's JS file is included beforehand.

Comment: mine has all included, and still setContent is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find what you need here: http://pastebin.com/sj8QA4xx - it shows how to get use nicEditor's API to insert text at the current cursor location. I am using it successfully to programatically modify a nicEditor's contents. Good luck!